# Laravel Queue Allowed memory size

Tags: php, laravel, file, queue

I have project based on Laravel 5.1, so I have a problem with sending a file via curl to another host. In my PHP conf I have memory_limit is 128M, and via CURL I am sending file which size is 100mb, (I am using Laravel Queue), but the response I have got following error

> allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   31860068 bytes) PHP

**I DONT WANT TO CHANGE memory_limit in my PHP conf**

```
 $storage = $this->configs[ 'storage' ];
    if( isset( $this->configs[ 'old_storage' ] ) ) {
        $old_storage = $this->configs[ 'old_storage' ];
    } else {
        throw new \Exception( 'Not found old storage' );
    }

    $files = $old_storage->files()->withTrashed()->get();

    try {
        if( $old_storage->testConnection()[ 'status' ] != 'true' ) {
            throw new \Exception( ufl( 'disk::disk.not_connection' ) . ' ' . $old_storage->name );
        }

        if( $storage->testConnection()[ 'status' ] != 'true' ) {
            throw new \Exception( ufl( 'disk::disk.not_connection' ) . ' ' . $storage->name );
        }

        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            try {
                $stream = $file->readStream();
                $file->setStorage( $storage->id );

                $file->storage()->getDriver()->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );

                $file->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );
            } catch( \Exception $e ) {
                $file->setStorage( $storage->id );
            }
            $file->save();
        }

        $old_storage->is_active = 0;
        $old_storage->status    = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $old_storage->save();
        $old_storage = null;
        $storage->is_active = 1;
        $storage->status    = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $storage->save();
        $storage = null;
    } catch( \Exception $e ) {
        //Откат
        foreach( $files as $file ) {
            $file->setStorage( $old_storage->id );
            $file->save();
        }

        $storage->status = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $storage->save();

        $old_storage->status = DiskStorage::STATUS_OK;
        $old_storage->save();

        throw new \Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }
```

**I am using sync driver and the file transfer working via webdav**

Comment: can you show more? it could be just the code that have a leak

Comment: `try {
                    $stream = $file->readStream();
                    $file->setStorage( $storage->id );

                    $file->storage()->getDriver()->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );

                    $file->putStream( $file->getRealDestination(), $stream );
                } catch( \Exception $e ) {
                    $file->setStorage( $storage->id );
                }
                $file->save();`